# Replicating matlab-style plot commands in f#

Tags: f#

I have a program that does a sequence of operations on 2D numerical arrays (e.g., int [,] or float [,]) where I have code like:

```
    let a3 = array |> f1 |> f2 |> f3
```

In Matlab or Octave, I would write this code like:

```
    a1 = f1(array);
    a2 = f2(a1);
    a3 = f3(a2);
```

During development, I often want to look at the intermediate values as an image, like this:

```
    a1 = f1(array);
    figure;imshow(a1);
    a2 = f2(a1);
    figure;imshow(a2);
    a3 = f3(a2);
```

Is there a straightforward way to write a routine in F# with a signature like:

```
    val myplot: 'a [,] -> ()
```

Where this function opens a window containing a canvas onto which I can plot the corresponding array, and then immediately returns.  Given such a thing, I could
write:

```
    let plotThrough (x: 'a [,]) =
      myplot x
      x
```

Which would allow my pipeline to become:

```
   let a3 = array |> f1 |> plotThrough |> f2 |> plotThrough |> f3
```

In which case two independent windows would appear, one containing my plot for the result of f1 and one for the result of f2.

The issue I have is not the drawing onto a canvas part (that is easy - ask for a Graphics context, draw into it), but how to generate a window for each plot command such that I can obtain the graphics context to draw into.  I have a limited test harness that is a statically designed forms GUI that has a couple of Images present that give me graphics contexts, but I'd prefer to not have to design a form each time I want to try a different pipeline with a different number of plots I want to look at.

Note: I am not interested in solutions that assume one is working with the fsi REPL - I want to be able to have an executable that, when run, will pop up a set of windows for each plot and then wait for all of them to be closed before it terminates.

Comment: Perhaps you'll find this useful: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/10/19/visual-value-verification